# Работа с массивом байтов C#

Tags: c#, массивы, byte

Добрый день, собственно настало то время когда мне нужно работать с массивом байтов, а я в них ни тю, тю, изучал их мельком, собственно суть вопроса.

У меня есть массив байтов 'Data', и мне нужно их передать в 'SendAsync(data.Data, 20);'

Если я передаю их напрямую то вылазит исключение - StackOverflowException.

И как я понял мне надо создать какой то BlockSize (Или как то так) типа - var buff = new byte[3840];

Вот что принимает SendAsync - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно что мне делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `StackOverflowException` возникает от рекурсивного вызова без проверки. Массивы байт тут не при чём, ищите ошибку в другом месте с отладчиком.

Answer (score 3):

[Массив](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) в C# - это область памяти, перед которой идут указатель на тип элемента массива и количество элементов.

В SendAsync ты можешь посылать всё что тебе угодно, никаких ограничений нет. Если ты получаешь ошибку [`StackOverflowException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx), это значит что область памяти, выделенная под стек текущего потока исчерпана. По-умолчанию размер стека - 1 МБ. Если ты не занимаешься ручным выделением памяти, то с вероятностью в 98% это рекурсивные вызовы. Чаще всего - вызов одного и того же метода из себя самого. Реже - длинная цепь рекурсивных вызовов на большом количестве элементов (н.п. разворачивание контейнеров на файловой системе). В этом случае поможет переход к [хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Могу предположить, что в твоём случае событие `MediaDataSent` райсится после отправки данных, сохраняя контекст вызовов, формируя таким образом бесконечную цепочку вызовов. Проверить это можно, раскомментировав строчку с отправкой данных, встав в этом месте в отладчике, и пропустив несколько итераций. После этого посмотри в окно стека вызовов.

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vc5KEXwUQGK0jUGFjZUBIA.png

https://image.prntscr.com/image/VmqlNaCSSkGrpkWwSNy7Zw.png

Вот.

Comment: Вот после того, как ты упал со `StackOverflowException` открой окно вызовов. **Debug -> Windows -> Call stack (Отладка -> Окна -> Стек вызовов)**

Comment: Я уже разобрался, это я накосячил, спасибо :)

Comment: Разобрался - напиши в чём была проблема и закрой вопрос.